# Angular new window with state management

Tags: angular, angular5, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-router-store

- Problem Statement:

I have a requirement: to open a new window in angular 6 and establish two way communication between the primary and secondary window.

- What I tried

I created a service WindowRef to open a new window/tab using angular "Window".
I created an @ngrx/store system to manage state in the app.
I am able to manage application state for any number of actions in the primary window, however when I open a new window and try accessing the state, it returns null.

If I can maintain state I can try and use ngStore to dispatch actions and try and establish two way communication channel between the primary and secondary opened window.

Can someone please suggest/ point me to a way to implement the above requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngrx/store` works in memory, meaning that if you refresh your page (or open a new tab) the current state in the Store will be lost.

If you want to communicate between both windows you can implement some sort of server side communication, e.g. [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/).

Another option without server would be to store the state/actions in your `localStorage` and listen to changes in the `localStorage` to update the state in a window.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I was able to communicate from Window 1 => Window 2 using the StateManegement and localStorage together. The issue I had was more communicating back from Window 2 => Window 1 (which completes the duplex communication).

How do I listen to localStotrage changes in angular 6? Did you mean pub/sub model?

Comment: I tried implementing to localStorage changes using this way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46078714/watch-for-changes-in-localstorage-angular2 however, my scenario is that I am listening to localStorage changes in a different browser tab or window. Will this still work? because it does not, can you suggest

Comment: mate it works like a charm, i used window.eventListerner to communicate and works like a gem.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for answering your question when you found a solution.